# TFS 2010 - Undo "Get This Version" Action

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs

So i click on `Get This Verision` (A really old one) under history by mistake and now my project has my new recent changes plus this very old changeset, but I am not sure what else might have changed (i see some of my new files created after this version with an exclamation mark)??. Is there a way I can undo the action of `Get this version` so my solution only has the changes I have been working on. Any help is appreciated thank you!

**UPDATE**: is it as easy as clicking `Get Latest`? That seemed to do the trick but now I still have all these conflicts to resolve from. Do i click `Keep Local Version` even though the description of that button says `This option will replace the server version with the content from your local version`. I do not want to replace the server version. I want to keep my local and leave the server version of this changeset alone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's as easy as clicking "Get Latest". The message you're seeing is misleading. "Get Latest" only affects your local workspace, it doesn't change anything on the server side at all.

Comment: thanks I was a little nervous at first, and well I had too many items checked out for my own good. Thanks for the confirmation!

Comment: I would resolve conflicts in the merge tool though - keep local is bad is somebody changed that file after you fid original get!